# Convert string of unicode character into unicode type

Tags: nlp, python-unicode

I have a list of string of gujarati unicode characters and i want to convert them to unicode. But the problem is the escape character('').
for eg

```
a="\\u0aec"
print(type(a))
# <type 'str'>
```

How to convert it into Unicode which is ('\u0aec')?
Also don't think about using `.encode('utf-8')` as it will just make it a unicode string and not unicode characters.

Comment: Don't understand the question - this _is_ unicode (you can write r"\u0aec" if you don't want the backslash shown escaped). Each string in Python3 is Unicode (e.g. consists of unicode characters).

Comment: Note that if you print a `list` of such strings (`print(my_list_of_strings)`), the escaped form (in fact, the repr) of each string will be printed.  If you were to print each string separately (`for s in my_list_of_strings:print(s)`), the unescaped forms will be printed, fonts and terminal configuration permitting.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=u"\u0aec"
```

Read the docs:

- [String literals - Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals): *A prefix of `'u'` or `'U'` makes the string a Unicode string.*
- [String and Bytes literals - Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals): *New in version 3.3: Support for the unicode legacy literal (`u'value'`) was reintroduced to simplify the maintenance of dual Python 2.x and 3.x codebases. See [PEP 414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414) for more information.*

There are more articles about the key differences between Python 2.7.x and Python 3.x; for instance **[Unicode](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#unicode)**:

> Python 2 has ASCII `str()` types, separate `unicode()`, but no `byte`
> type.
>
> Now, in Python 3, we finally have Unicode (utf-8) `str`ings, and 2
> byte classes: `byte` and `bytearray`s.